# Xcode: Button won't show in portrait, only landscape

Tags: xcode, uibutton, autolayout

I'm new so I'm not trying to do anything fancy here. Just learning the basics. I'm sure this is something overly simple but I'm completely missing it.

I have a button that's aligned vertically and horizontally in the work space with a specified width and height as well. All the lines are blue and I don't get any errors but when I try to view in the preview or simulator the button doesn't appear in portrait view, only landscape.

Under the general tab I have my app set to portrait only.

What am I doing wrong?

Here's a video demonstrating the problem: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BD835dCyBSQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so after messing around with xCode for sometime I was able to recreate your problem. And the problem is there is no problem :D . 
What's happening is that you are using size class **w Compact and h Compact** . Which is for specifically for iphones 3.5 inch, 4 inch and 4.7 inch in landscape mode.

So if you want to set autolayout for views in both landscape mode and portrait mode you should use other size classes like. "**w Compact h Any"** or "**w Any h Any"**

So here are the size classes and it's target orientation and sizes.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I was just using the single square because I'm using an 11" macbook air. I thought with auto layout it didn't matter. I guess it does. I switched it to the "For all iPhones in portrait" but when I do that my button disappears. Are you not allowed the change the width/height of the storyboard in the middle of a project?

Comment: Yes it's not possible to add a view in "w Compact and h compact" and see it on other size classes. So the best bet would be to add a view in size class "wAny and hAny" and then modify constraints for other size classes. You could play with same view like that.

Comment: I'm so confused. I thought changing the w/h around just changed the canvas area. What does it actually do? I noticed when I changed the w/h the button was still in the "View Controller Scene" Tree view but "Button" has transparent/disabled until I changed back to the original w/h.